# gcc-4.0 failed on mac 10.6.8 while installing Scrapy how can i overcome this?

Tags: python, pip, scrapy

I used pip install Scrapy on my mac 10.6.8 and i get the error below
can anyone help me please?

```
creating build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport

copying twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/iocpsupport.c ->
build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport

copying twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/winsock_pointers.c ->
build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport

copying twisted/python/_epoll.c ->
build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/twisted/python

copying twisted/python/_initgroups.c ->
build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/twisted/python

copying twisted/runner/portmap.c ->
build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/twisted/runner

copying twisted/test/raiser.c ->
build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/twisted/test

running build_ext

gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch ppc -arch i386
-g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c conftest.c -o conftest.o

/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.0.1/as: assembler
(/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or
/usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not
installed

Installed assemblers are:

/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64

/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386

lipo: can't open input file:
/var/folders/jk/jkTyAFDWEC8fvZts+C7Jwk+++TI/-Tmp-//ccBIdB4l.out (No
such file or directory)

gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch ppc -arch i386
-g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c conftest.c -o conftest.o

conftest.c:1:23: error: sys/epoll.h: No such file or directory

conftest.c:1:23: error: sys/epoll.h: No such file or directory

lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of:
/var/folders/jk/jkTyAFDWEC8fvZts+C7Jwk+++TI/-Tmp-//cceIymsT.out

building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/twisted

creating build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/twisted/test

gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch ppc -arch i386
-g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c twisted/test/raiser.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/twisted/test/raiser.o

In file included from /usr/include/architecture/i386/math.h:626,

                 from /usr/include/math.h:28,

                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pyport.h:312,

                 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:58,

                 from twisted/test/raiser.c:4:

/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:108:14: warning: #warning Building
for Intel with Mac OS X Deployment Target < 10.4 is invalid.

/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.0.1/as: assembler
(/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or
/usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not
installed

Installed assemblers are:

/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64

/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386

lipo: can't open input file:
/var/folders/jk/jkTyAFDWEC8fvZts+C7Jwk+++TI/-Tmp-//ccNvrcyZ.out (No
such file or directory)

error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1

---------------------------------------- Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
-c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/bbb/Dropbox/projects/android/continuous-integration/build/Twisted/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n',
'\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed
--record /var/folders/jk/jkTyAFDWEC8fvZts+C7Jwk+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-MXEZuX-record/install-record.txt
failed with error code 1 Storing complete log in
/Users/bbb/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have installed Xcode 4 which removed the `gcc-4.0` used to build the Python 2.7 you have installed.  From the path names in the traceback, chances are that was a 32-bit-only Python downloaded from python.org.  With Xcode 4, you should try installing the [latest 64-bit/32-bit OS X installer for Python 2.7 from python.org](http://www.python.org/download/) instead.  You will then likely need to re-install any packages you had installed, like `Distribute`, `pip`, and dependencies.  Depending on which version of Xcode 4, you may also need to supply the following environment variable setting before running `pip` or `easy_install`:

```
export CC=gcc
```

Comment: Hi I downloaded the python27 dmg from python.org installed and then did pip install Scrapy i get this:$ pip install Scrapy
setuptools;__file__='/Users/bbb/Dropbox/projects/android/continuous-integration/build/Twisted/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /var/folders/jk/jkTyAFDWEC8fvZts+C7Jwk+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-J88r8N-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /Users/tomerb/.pip/pip.log

Comment: usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:108:14: warning: #warning Building for Intel with Mac OS X Deployment Target < 10.4 is invalid.

/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.0.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed

Comment: Installed assemblers are:

/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64

/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386

lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/jk/jkTyAFDWEC8fvZts+C7Jwk+++TI/-Tmp-//ccOTQaBa.out (No such file or directory)

error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Did you install new versions of Distribute and pip after reinstalling Python? Or are you using a virtualenv?  From the messages you show you still appear to be using a 32-bit-only Python.  When you type just `python`, the interpreter version info displayed should say 2.7.2 and gcc-4.2, not gcc-4.0.  Then follow the pip install instructions including installing Distribute: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

Comment: Hi 1. I did not install new pip after installing python because i saw that pip was already working, do i need to reinstall it also in that case?. 2. I have virtualenv but in this case i don't think i was using it, shoudl i be using it? will it help? 3. Yes my computer is 32 bit so i use 32 bit python (32 bit only that is probably...) so you say i need to reinstall pip right?

Comment: easy_install (supplied by either setuptools or Distribute) and pip are associated with a particular Python instance; in general, you need to install both of them for each Python you want to use them with.  Note that Apple supplies easy_install versions (in `/usr/bin`) for each of the system Pythons.  Don't use them. I would not use `virtualenv` until you have the basics straightened out first.  `virtualenv` is somewhat less important on OS X than on other platforms thanks to framework builds.  The 64-bit/32-bit installer will work just fine on any machine supported by 10.6 or 10.7.

Comment: thanks i managed to do it also when i added export ARCHFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64' in addition to export CC=gcc

Answer (score 0):

pip installs python packages. Ofthen Those python packages  depend on c libaries which should be installed by your package manager and which are not installed by pip.

Looking at the output your missing a couple of header files of packages. I could spot these there could be more..

```
conftest.c:1:23: error: sys/epoll.h: No such file or directory

include/python2.7/pyport.h:312
```

on ubuntu it is a simple look in the package manager for the:
 `python-dev`  and `epoll-dev` packages. but there is probably an easy way for osx to.

OR you can look for a precompiled package for your osx.